# Como mostrar registros de una tabla con javascript

Tags: javascript, php, select

El problema que tengo es que cuando quiero mostrar los registros de mi tabla, me sale este error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [{"id_usuario":"6","nombre":"pepe","correo":"pepe@gmail.com","contrasena":"pepe"}]**

Ya intenté utilizar el JSON.parse(response) pero al hacer eso se muestran los datos pero se borra el thead de la tabla.

```
function Listar() {
          $.ajax({
            url: "./controlador/usuarios.php",
            data: { "accion": "LISTAR" },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON"
          }).done(function (response) {
              var html = "";
              $.each(response, function (index, data) {
                html += "<tr>";
                html += "<td>" + data.nombre + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + data.correo + "</td>";
                html += "<td>" + data.contrasena + "</td>";
                html += "<td>";
                html +="<button class='btn btn-warning rounded-circle' onclick='Listar_Id(" + data.id_usuario +")'><i class='fas fa-pen'></i></button>";
                html +="<button class='btn btn-danger rounded-circle' onclick='Eliminar(" + data.id_usuario +")'><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></button>";
                html += "</td>";
                html += "</tr>";
              });
              document.getElementById("tablaUsuarios").innerHTML = html;
            }).fail(function (response) {
              alert(response);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Desde PHP le envias cabeceras json? algo asio `header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode( $arrJson ); `         si no lo envias. entonces en tu js      no coloques  `datatype: "json"`  si no colocalo asi  `datatype: "HTML"`

Comment: Se borran las cabeceras de la tabla html

Comment: si en tu js usas  `datatype: "HTML"` debes parsear con `JSON.parse(response)`

Comment: Envío así desde mi controlador echo json_encode($obj->listarUsuarios());

Comment: El problema es que al usar `innerHTML` estarías reemplazando el contenido existente, es por eso que los `thead` se borran. Prueba así: `document.getElementById("tablaUsuarios").innerHTML += html;` al usar `+=` en lugar de `=` se agregará el contenido a lo que ya existe en el elemento. Por otro lado si indicas `json` como dataType no necesitas hacer parse, pero debes garantizar que el servidor emite un json válido y poner un header que indique el content type y con codificación utf-8 siempre es recomendable.